# How to send 2 different kind of logs (with different pattern) with the same LSF to one logstash central

Tags: logstash, multiline, logstash-forwarder

I've got a log stash forward (LSF) agent that sends 2 kinds of logs to a Logstash central agent (version 2.2). 
These logs are multilines but not with the same pattern..

In the LSF the config file is like that :

```
{ "network": {
"servers": [ "server1:77009" ],
"timeout": 15,
"ssl ca": "logstashforwader.jks"  },  "files": [
{
  "paths": [
   "/dir1/log1"
            ],
  "fields": { "type": "type1",
    "environment": "env1" }
},
{
  "paths": [
   "/dir2/log2"
            ],
        "fields": { "type": "type2",
    "environment": "env1"  }
}   ]}
```

In the logstash central I'd like to apply the good pattern for the good type something like that :

```
input {if [type] == "type1" { lumberjack {
    host => "@IP"
    port => "77009"
    ssl_certificate => "/logstash-forwarder.crt"
    ssl_key => "/logstash-forwarder.key"
            codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^%{DATE_EU}"
            max_lines => 750
            negate => true
            what => previous
            }
    }} else if [type] == "type2" { lumberjack {
    host => "server1"
    port => "77009"
    ssl_certificate => "logstash-forwarder.crt"
    ssl_key => "/logstash-forwarder.key"
            codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^<"
            negate => true
            what => previous
            }
    }}}
```

But it doesn't work ... Is it the best way (or is it possible to put an "or" in the pattern line ?)

After I'll apply different grok on each "type".

Answer (score 0):

You can't use conditionals on inputs.

You can use an or ("|") in your multiline pattern to support both inputs.

You could also use two different ports and send each input to a different port.

Comment: I add "|" in the multiline pattern and it works very well !!  Thx

Comment: Good news.  Any chance you could accept the answer?